# NetAdvantage 9.1 & Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, infragistics

Will Ingragistic's NetAdvantage 9.1 work with visual studio 2010? 
I installed VS 2010, and then NetAdvantage but I don't see the NetAdvantage in VS.

Comment: I Have the same problem. even i have the framework 3.5 , but still i can't see Infragestic9.1 controls in VS2010 tool box, any Suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go into your project properties and change the Target framework on the Application tab to one of the full versions instead of the .NET Framework  Client Profile. Support for the client profiles was not added until 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all of the desired assemblies, drag and drop them into the toolbox --> http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.3/CLR2.0/?page=Introduction_Using_the_Choose_Toolbox_Items_Dialog_Box.html

Click the "Dragging Assemblies from the Bin Folder" link at the bottom of the page. This works for other 3rd party components as well.